# Chrome notification ignoring eventTime

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I am trying to send a notification with from a Chrome Extension background page with a one-minute delay, but the notification is sent immediately. The NotificationOption that I am using is "eventTime":

```
var tm = Date.now();
tm += 60000;
var opt = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Homework Reminder",
    message: "It worked!",
    iconUrl: "images/asc.png",
    eventTime: tm
  };
chrome.notifications.create("", opt, function(id) {alert(new Date(tm));});
```

Everything works except the delay. How do I send a notification at a future time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

```
A timestamp associated with the notification, in milliseconds past the epoch (e.g. Date.now() + n).
```

So I don't think it was made for notification in the future. You should use regular setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var opt = {
        type: "basic",
        title: "Homework Reminder",
        message: "It worked!",
        iconUrl: "images/asc.png",
        eventTime: tm
      };
    chrome.notifications.create("", opt, function(id) {alert(new Date(tm));});
    }, 60000);
```

Comment: Jean-Francois - I wanted the notification to be sent whether the browser was running or not, so I used chrome.alarms.create instead of setTimeout. Thanks for getting me started in the right direction.

Comment: The problem with `setTimeout` is that if the background page is unloaded, the timeout goes away.  An `alarm` will avoid this problem.

Comment: What's the purpose of `eventTime` then? If either `setTimeout` or `chrome.alarms` is used, do we necessarily need to add `eventTime` in the options?

Answer (score 2):

To follow-up on Jim's comment, you need to use chrome.alarms.create to postpone creation of the notification. It is advisable to add the alarm event handler to your background.js file (or whatever script specified in manifest.json for background).

For example (in background.js):

```
// Add alarm listener from runtime onInstalled listener.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

   chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {

      var opts = {};
      opts.type = "basic";
      opts.iconUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL("/images/logo.png");
      opts.title = "Notification Title";
      opts.message = "Message is here";
      opts.eventTime = alarm.scheduledTime();

      chrome.notifications.create(alarm.name, opts, function() {
         console.log("Notification created", nopts);
      });
   });
});
```

You may want to use chrome.storage keyed on the alarm name to construct unique notifications per alarm.