# what's the purpose of eventTime in NotificationOptions of chrome.notifications API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

When [creating a notification](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/#method-create) from an extension using [`chrome.notifications`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/) API, the [NotificationOptions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/#type-NotificationOptions): [`eventTime`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/#property-NotificationOptions-eventTime) seems to be ignored as the notification is created immediately which supposed to be delayed by milliseconds set for `eventTime`. As per documentation:

> `eventTime`
> A timestamp associated with the notification, in milliseconds past the epoch (e.g. Date.now() + n).

Although this is not clearly stated that this will cause a delay in creation of the notification by the milliseconds set in `eventTime`, then what's the purpose of this option?

---

I found a similar question was asked some years ago: [Chrome notification ignoring eventTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22571870/725306) but the above question was not answered there. Instead the solution was talking about the other approaches (`setTimeout`, `chrome.alarms`) to delay the creation of notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code, eventTime does not delay the notification.

- **It's displayed in the title of the notification** ([source](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/notifications/win/notification_template_builder.cc;l=122;drc=e616817db21522ec8aa6efd2f48b73697d010281)).

  For example, setting it to  `Date.now() + (5 * 60 + 1) * 1000` shows `In 5m` i.e. five minutes.

  [image]

  Note that we had to add one second, otherwise the API shows `4m` as it subtracts the few microseconds spent in creating the notification internally.
- **It's used to sort notifications within the same priority group** ([source](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/message_center/notification_list.cc;drc=e616817db21522ec8aa6efd2f48b73697d010281;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=36))

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. But on Windows 10 the event time seems not displayed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZONI.png

Comment: The message center doesn't support it, I guess. I've disabled it in Win10 so I see Chrome's own UI.